# Breaking infinite loop which waits for console input java

Tags: java, telnet

I have a telnet code in Java using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient

And i am providing login information by reading "login:" from telnet server via below code,

```
    in = telnet.getInputStream();
    char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length()-1);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    char ch = (char) in.read();
    while (true) {
       System.out.print(ch);
       sb.append(ch);
       if (ch == lastChar) {
         if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
            return sb.toString();
         }
       }
       ch = (char) in.read();
       i++;
       // System.out.print(i);
    }
```

But when i give a invalid telnet server which prompts eg "username:", it results in infinite loop waiting for "login:" in "in.read();"

as its waits in in.read(), i cant use any flag or others in while(_flag) too.
Can anyone provide me a solution for avoiding infinite loop when it application receives invalid login.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a separate thread, which would exit after your desired time.
2. You will need to control this separate thread using a `boolean` variable as flag, a `while` loop, and `break`.
3. Set this flag to true in the method which returns when your connection to the telnet is a success, and this will `break` the loop within that separate thread.
4. If this doesn't happen within that stipulated time, then that separate thread will do a `System.exit(0)`, so you program ends.

Answer (score 1):

You have a success criteria (telnet server sends `login:`) but not a fail criteria. So the loop may run forever.

What should happen to break the loop on failure? Think about a condition. Maybe: "try for 20 seconds" or "`login:` hasn't been sent within the first 100 chars".

You could aswell read line by line and expect that the first line the server sends (within a certain time interval) is equal to `login:`, otherwise exit with error message (that's what I'd do in your case)